# spark vs pandas dataframe (with large columns) head(n) in jupyter notebook

Tags: scala, pandas, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook

Now a days, data comes with large number of features. To get a short summary of data, people load data in data frames and use `head()` method to display it. Its pretty common to run experiments using Jupyter Notebooks (with Toree for scala).

Spark (scala) is good for handling large amount of data, but its `head()` method doesn't show column headers in horizontally scrollable notebook.

Pandas Dataframe head
[image: Pandas Dataframe Head]
Spark Scala Dataframe head
[image: Spark Scala Dataframe Head]

I know you can get column header in scala dataframe by using .columns, but printing it doesn't display header along data columns making it difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `df.head(20)` try `df.show(n=20, truncate=False)`. Here is the detailed [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.show).

Comment: For python, i can use both pyspark & pandas together, so no such issue will come. Question is about spark in scala (your doc: pyspark, correct doc:https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset).  Output of df.show() is not readable for large number of columns.

Comment: I tried already, it gives garbage output. Try yourself with dataframe with 100 columns. In fact Scala version has one more argument "vertical", but it displays row by row vertically. But, I am looking for nice tabular display horizontally scrollable like-df.head(10), but with scrollable column header.

Comment: Pandas is tightly embedded with jupyter so it do all nice stuff. But here is the trick, convert you spark dataframe to pandas dataframe. I don't have jupyter to try out now hope this will solve your problem `df.limit(20).toPandas().head()`

Comment: You are not getting the issue. This is about scala spark, not pyspark. toPandas doesn't work for scala.